# Twilio voicemail - Get a call back if caller hangs up before recording starts

Tags: twilio

## Question

Implementing voicemail in Twilio. How can I get a call back if the caller hangs up before the recording starts?

## More info

After the incoming call's `<dial>` times out, the call back URL responds with this:

```
<Response>
    <Say>Please leave a message.</Say>
    <Record playBeep="true" action="http://..." />
</Response>
```

The issue I seem to be having is that if the caller hangs up while the `<Say>` verb is executing, the `<Record>` verb never executes and thus the application never receives a call back.

Is it possible to receive a call back under this circumstance? If so, how do I make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

One idea might be to separate this TwiML response into two separate responses and track what the last step in your workflow you sent to the call was.  First send the Say:

```
<Response>
    <Say>Please leave a message.</Say>
    <Redirect>http://example.com/record</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Then redirect to the Record:

```
<Response>
    <Record playBeep="true" action="http://..." />
</Response>
```

To get notified when the call ends, set the StatusCallback attribute on your phone number.  When Twilio makes the request to the StatusCallback URL, you can check to see what the last step that you sent to the user was and take the appropriate action.

Hope that helps.